# org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: Неизвестный тип данных при обновлении БД

Tags: java, h2, spring-jdbc

Пытаюсь сделать обновление БД по условию используя **JdbcTemplate.update**

```
public Clothes updateClothes(Clothes clothes) {
    String type_Clothes = clothes.getTypeClothes().toString();
    String size = clothes.getSize().toString();
    String color = clothes.getColor().toString();
    int cotton = clothes.getCotton();
    int quantity = clothes.getQuantity();

    String sql = "merge into CLOTHES_REP c " +
            "using (SELECT ? as type_Clothes,  ? as size, ? as color, ? as cotton, ? as quantity from dual) d " +
            "on (c.type_Clothes = d.type_Clothes, c.size = d.size, c.color = d.color, c.cotton = d.cotton) " +
            "when matched then update " +
            "set c.quantity = d.quantity " +
            "when not matched then insert (type_Clothes, size, color, cotton, quantity) " +
            "values(d.type_Clothes, d.size, d.color, d.quantity)";

    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, type_Clothes, size, color, cotton, quantity);
    return clothes;
}
```

вылетает ошибка:

> Unknown data type: "TYPE_CLOTHES"; SQL statement:
> merge into CLOTHES_REP c using (SELECT ? as type_Clothes,  ? as size, ? as color, ? as cotton, ? as quantity from dual) d on (c.type_Clothes = d.type_Clothes, c.size = d.size, c.color = d.color, c.cotton = d.cotton) when matched then update set c.quantity = d.quantity when not matched then insert (type_Clothes, size, color, cotton, quantity) values(d.type_Clothes, d.size, d.color, d.quantity) [50004-214];

пользовался подсказками:
[How to insert/update a single record using a MERGE statement with Spring JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711617/how-to-insert-update-a-single-record-using-a-merge-statement-with-spring-jdbc)

На всякий случай кусок работающего запроса:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(
            "insert into CLOTHES_REP (type_Clothes, size, color, cotton, quantity) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            clothes.getTypeClothes().toString(),
            clothes.getSize().toString(),
            clothes.getColor().toString(),
            clothes.getCotton(),
            clothes.getQuantity());
```

Comment: Показанный пример относится к БД Oracle, не факт, что он будет работать в H2.  Похожий пример (без ответа) [Merge query in H2 database giving "Unknown data type:" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72131178/).   Пример с исправленным запросом MERGE для H2: [H2 MERGE INTO ... USING with multiple values, do NOT update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49956588/)

Comment: @NowhereMan спасибо за наводку, буду пробовать